# Match words of string column in a table with words of string in another column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have two tables for example take two small input tables:-

```
Table1:-

columnA   
man got wounded by dog  
joe met sally  



Table2:-  
ColumnB  
life is good  
dog man got hunt   
dumb man wounded iron
```

I want to search for a row in columnA the row from columnB with maximum matching words for Eg:-

```
Intermediate Output of above table should be:-
ColumnA    ColumnB    words_matching  number_of_words 
"man got wounded by dog"   "dumb man wounded iron"    "man,wounded"  2  
"man got wounded by dog"    "dog man got hunt"    "dog,man,got"   3
```

In final result output i want to show:-

```
ColumnA    ColumnB    words_matching  number_of_words 
"man got wounded by dog"    "dog man got hunt"    "dog,man,got"   3
```

P.S:- I have provided the output for only one case,the table will be huge. Also couldn't add spaces between column data so used quotes.

I have tried doing the above my breaking the string using heirarchial query but it takes a lot time:-
example of how i break the string:-

```
select column1,regexp_substr(column1,'[^ ]+', 1, level) break_1 from table1
 connect by regexp_substr(column1,'[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Below is another query i came up with but don't think its a good idea for huge data as the performance is very low due to cartesian join:

```
 select st1,st2,
 max(round((extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select cardinality (
  sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(''' || replace(replace(lower(st1),''''), ' ', ''',''' ) || ''') multiset intersect
  sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('''||replace(replace(lower(st2),''''), ' ', ''',''' )||'''))  x from dual'), '//text()')),2))  seq
  from (
  select l1.column1 st1,l2.column2 st2
  from
  table1 l1,table2 l2 ) group by st1,st2;
```

Can someone suggest a good approach--

Comment: Do you only want values from table2.columnB that are contained completely in table1.columnA?

Comment: No ,apologize for not giving proper example. I want to fetch that column for table B that has maximum number of matching words for a row in column A. editing my post also

Comment: Do you want to penalize words from table2 that are not contained in table1? I.e. should "life is good but too short" get a lower score than "life is good" if you match against "life is good"? (according to your example, both would get number_of_words = 3)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt :- Since i don't have any string with either 'life' or ' is' or 'good' in table1 , it need not be returned.I want the string in table1 and the most matching string in table2. By most matching i mean number of words that match between table1's string and table2's string should be highest

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SOUNDEX might help

Comment: @eric.itzhak :- Soundex is not what i need as it just assigns value according to "sounds like"

Answer (score 1):

I found faster solution to my problem above, am using procedure to break the strings and store in different tables ,then using those tables to find the matching strings.

Procedure:-

```
create or replace
procedure split_string_word_match 
as 
type varr is table of  varchar(4000);
list1 varr;
list2 varr;

begin
select distinct column1 bulk collect into list1 from table1 ;
select distinct column2 bulk collect into list2 from table2 ;

for k in list1.first..list1.last
loop
insert into list1_result
select list1(k),regexp_substr(list1(k),'[^ ]+', 1, level) break_1 from dual
 connect by regexp_substr(list1(k),'[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null;
commit;
end loop;

for i in list2.first..list2.last
loop
insert into list2_result
select list2(i),regexp_substr(list2(i),'[^ ]+', 1, level) break_2 from dual
 connect by regexp_substr(list2(i),'[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null;
commit;
end loop;
end;
/
```

then using the sql below over the result tables to find the most matching string:-(works faster than many loops in procedure,hence wrote a SQL)

```
select st1,st2,cs_string ,max(cnt) max_count
from (
select l1.column1 st1,l2.column2 st2,listagg(l1.break_1,',') within group(order by l1.break_1) cs_string ,count(1) cnt
from list1_result l1,list2_result l2
where l1.break_1 = l2.break_1
group by l1.column1,l2.column2)
group by st1,st2,cs_string;
```